# HashMap: Getting all the values in the HashMap by decrypting an encrypted string in a function

Tags: java, hashmap

The program keeps track of the cars which have been sold from a showroom.
The system should allow him to

- add a new car
- get a specific car's details bsed on its registration number
- get details of all the cars

Car details include the chassis
number, make, model, engine_capacity and year of registration. The National ID
number of the buyer is also stored along with the details of the car. All these
details are kept in a single string, whereby each component is separated by '!'.
The system should allow indexing of cars based on their registration number
(which is a string).
For example if a car is sold with the following details:

Registration No: : 1910JN2011
Chassis number : 23432-423
Make : BMW
Model : X5
Engine Capacity : 3000 cc
Year Registration : 2011
Buyer ID : S012345678910

A key-value pair in the map would be:
"1910JN2011" -> 23432-423!BMW!X5!3000!2011!S012345678910”

Here is what I have worked out :

```
public class dsa_qu2c {

//Function display(String G) takes as input the string and displays the attributes
public static void display(String G){

    String Details[]= G.split("!");

    //split() allows splitting of a string based "!" and returns an array of strings

    System.out.println("Chassis Number:\t"+Details[0]);
    System.out.println("Make:\t"+Details[1]);
    System.out.println("Model:\t"+Details[2]);
    System.out.println("Engine Capacity:\t"+Details[3]);
    System.out.println("Year of Registration:\t"+Details[4]);
    System.out.println("Buyer NIC:\t"+Details[5]);

}

public static int menu(){
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

    int choice;

    System.out.println("1:Add a car.");
    System.out.println("2:Display car based on registration number");
    System.out.println("3:Display all details of car");

    choice=sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();

    return choice;


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String S= ""; //Compiled string to be stored as value in the hashmap
    String R= ""; //Registration number to be stored as key in the hashmap

    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

    int choice;

    HashMap<String, String> HMap= new HashMap<String, String>();

    while(true){
        choice= menu();
              switch(choice)
              {
              case 1 : {

                  System.out.println("Enter registration number");
                  R= sc.nextLine();
                  System.out.println("Enter compiled string");
                  S= sc.nextLine();

                  HMap.put(R,S);
                  break;
              }

              case 2: {

                  System.out.println("Enter registration number");
                  R= sc.nextLine();
                  String value= HMap.get(R);

                  display(value);
                  break;
              }

              case 3: {

                  for(Map.Entry entry: HMap.entrySet()){

                      display((String)entry.getValue());
                      break;

                  }
              }

              case 4: {
                  System.exit(0);
              }

              default: {
                  break;
              }
              }
    }

 }
}
```

Only `Case 3` where the system has to retrieve data for all the cars is not working as nothing is being displayed when I choose that option.

Comment: Can you add an example execution to your question? e.g. Click 1, add data, click 2, display one, click 3, display all. This works fine with dummy data for me.

Comment: Also your break needs to be outside the loop for case 3

Comment: @pandaadb Thanks, the `break` was causing a prob. I removed it and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove **break;** from case 3:

```
          case 3: {

              for(Map.Entry entry: HMap.entrySet()){

                  display((String)entry.getValue());
                  //break;

              }
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

Put *break* after for loop in case 3 . Removing break doesn’t actually make good coding practice when you are using switch case